# Section/chapter title in landscape mode

Tags: sectioning, landscape

How could I write the title of a section or of a chapter in landscape mode?

I mean without rotating the document. What I need to have, to explain me better, is this:

[image]

Do't mind about the plot, I already created a page with the landscape mode for the plot and it's awesome.

What I miss is the "title of this section" in landscape mode, above the plot.

Thank you!!

I already inserted the plot with the cose

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=2.5]{E1-ExpLog-LogLogPlot.eps}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

What I need is the title in section mode above the plot, in landscape mode.

Let's pretend I have to write "TITILE OF THE PLOT" as I wrote in the paper.

Comment: We would need your code for the plot in landscape mode. If I understand well, you want the plot  rotated, but a ‘normal’ section title?

Comment: @Bernard I'll add the code in the question to make it clearer

Comment: How does this differ from rotating the document? That is, why not use the `landscape` environment for the plot and title? (Load e.g. `pdflscape` or whatever.)

Comment: @cfr I actually did not think about that! o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it something like this you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx, rotating, caption, lscape, threeparttable}% \usepackage{amsmath}

 \begin{document}

\begin{landscape} \section{About Piero di Cosimo}
 \vfill
 \begin{measuredfigure}
\includegraphics[height=10cm]{SanRomano}
        %
\caption{The Battle of San Romano}
    \end{measuredfigure}
\vfill
 \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, the Title shall be in landscape mode, at the left of the image you put. I wrote "above" but I expressed myself bad: I meant "above" with respect to the landscape mode lol

Comment: @Alan Turing: I've modified my answer. Is it more like you want (sorry for the poor quality of the image!)?