# Section title above table in landscape mode

Tags: landscape

Like in this post ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342279/section-chapter-title-in-landscape-mode)) I would like to put the name of the appendix on the top of the page which is in landscape mode. In deviation of the one who started that topic, I would like to have the title of the page at the shortest side of the paper (so, at your right side if it is in landscape mode). I tried something similar as the one who answered that topic, but that does not work.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=155mm,top=23.5mm,bottom=23.5mm,
     footskip=40pt,heightrounded, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{appendix}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{left=3cm,bottom=0.1cm, top=1cm}
\begin{landscape} \section{Appendix}
    \setcounter{table}{0}
    \renewcommand*\thetable{\Alph{section}.\arabic{table}} \subsection{Unit root tests}
    \leavevmode\vfill
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \caption{P-values of Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test}
            \label{my-label}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}llllllllllllll@{}}
                \toprule
                Variable & Austria & Belgium & Finland & France & Germany & Netherl. & Greece & Italy & Ireland & Portugal & Spain & All eurozone & US \\ \midrule
                \textit{Yield-OIS (10y)} & 0.1807 & 0.1912 & 0.1255 & 0.3142 & 0.1641 & 0.1995 & 0.4182 & 0.4180 & 0.5964 & 0.6333 & 0.4743 & & \textbf{0.0437} \\
                \textit{CDS } & 0.0779 & 0.2706 & 0.3143 & 0.2230 & 0.0938 & 0.2775 & 0.7790 & 0.1399 & 0.2852 & 0.3403 & 0.2272 & & \\
                \textit{Redom} & \textbf{0.0005} & 0.1273 & \textbf{0.0001} & \textbf{0.0287} & & 0.0718 & 0.6975 & 0.2210 & 0.6008 & 0.5033 & 0.4064 & & \\
                \textit{BAS }& \textbf{0.0000} & \textbf{0.0111} & \textbf{0.0012} & \textbf{0.0000} & \textbf{0.0000} & 0.0021 & \textbf{0.0026} & 0.0000 & 0.3094 & 0.4802 & 0.0000 & & \\
                \textit{OIS rate (10y)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & & & & & & & & & & 0.8880 & 0.0907 \\
                \textit{VSTOXX} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & & & & & & & & & & & \textbf{0.0009} & \\
                \textit{CESI} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & & & & & & & & & & & \textbf{0.0246} & \textbf{0.0146} \\ \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]   \footnotesize{
                    \item \textbf{Notes}: This table shows the p-values of the Augmented Dickey-Fuller (ADF) test. The null hypothesis is that the variable has a unit root. This hypothesis is rejected when the p-value < 0.05 (highlighted in bold). The ADF with trend and intercept has been performed if variables have a clear trend. The column ''All eurozone'' shows the p-values for the time series observations. All variables in this test are measured in level values.}
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
    \vfill
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are all those packages really necessary in your minimal working example?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I forgot to delete the ones that are not relevant anymore. I edited my MWE.

Comment: sorry, where the section title should be? now it is in  landscape orientation on the left top page corner. do you like that it is at right page corner, or that it stay in place where it is in portrait orientation? if latter is the case, than page should stay in portrait orientation and  be only table rotated.

Comment: can you show a hand drawn sketch, which show page layout , table position on section title position?

Comment: Yes it is what you referred to as the latter. So, I would like to have the titles  (section and subsection) on the right page corner (which is the same as on the top corner in portrait mode). I have tried to do this with the rotate environment. However, the titles than do not fit on the page and the table is not centered. Especially the first is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want this?

[image: sideways tabular]

Note that you should not use `'` for an opening quotation mark. Use ` instead.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=155mm,top=23.5mm,bottom=23.5mm,footskip=40pt,heightrounded, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs,rotating}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{left=3cm,bottom=0.1cm, top=1cm}
\section{Appendix}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand*\thetable{\Alph{section}.\arabic{table}}
\subsection{Unit root tests}
\begingroup
\vfill
%\centering % uncomment to centre the table horizontally as well as vertically
\begin{sideways}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{P-values of Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}llllllllllllll@{}}
      \toprule
      Variable & Austria & Belgium & Finland & France & Germany & Netherl. & Greece & Italy & Ireland & Portugal & Spain & All eurozone & US \\ \midrule
      \textit{Yield-OIS (10y)} & 0.1807 & 0.1912 & 0.1255 & 0.3142 & 0.1641 & 0.1995 & 0.4182 & 0.4180 & 0.5964 & 0.6333 & 0.4743 & & \textbf{0.0437} \\
      \textit{CDS } & 0.0779 & 0.2706 & 0.3143 & 0.2230 & 0.0938 & 0.2775 & 0.7790 & 0.1399 & 0.2852 & 0.3403 & 0.2272 & & \\
      \textit{Redom} & \textbf{0.0005} & 0.1273 & \textbf{0.0001} & \textbf{0.0287} & & 0.0718 & 0.6975 & 0.2210 & 0.6008 & 0.5033 & 0.4064 & & \\
      \textit{BAS }& \textbf{0.0000} & \textbf{0.0111} & \textbf{0.0012} & \textbf{0.0000} & \textbf{0.0000} & 0.0021 & \textbf{0.0026} & 0.0000 & 0.3094 & 0.4802 & 0.0000 & & \\
      \textit{OIS rate (10y)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & & & & & & & & & & 0.8880 & 0.0907 \\
      \textit{VSTOXX} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & & & & & & & & & & & \textbf{0.0009} & \\
      \textit{CESI} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & & & & & & & & & & & \textbf{0.0246} & \textbf{0.0146} \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
      \footnotesize
        \item \textbf{Notes}: This table shows the p-values of the Augmented Dickey-Fuller (ADF) test. The null hypothesis is that the variable has a unit root. This hypothesis is rejected when the p-value < 0.05 (highlighted in bold). The ADF with trend and intercept has been performed if variables have a clear trend. The column ``All eurozone'' shows the p-values for the time series observations. All variables in this test are measured in level values.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{sideways}
\vfill
\restoregeometry
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

If you want the table centred horizontally, as Zarko suggests, simply uncomment the line indicated:

[image: table centred both ways]

EDITED in light of Zarko's suggestions/corrections.

Comment: For caption in `threeparttable` should be `caption` sufficient . From OP comment I understand, that the table should be vertical and *horizontal* centered. Horizontal centering can be achieved by adding of `\hfil` after first `\vfill` .

Comment: @Zarko Thanks :-). I didn't know that about `threeparttable`. Seems odd to me, but handy, perhaps. I would just use `\centering` for the horizontal centring, if that's needed, but you're obviously right that `\hfill` would work.